# when executing glm the 'gender' variable is suffixed by value(M)

Tags: r, glm

When I run 'glm' in R, the 'gender' variable is suffixed by M (for male). Does it has any special meaning or there is something wrong  in my code

```
>as.formula('response ~ gender + age + var1 +var2+var3+var4')
  response ~ gender + age + var1 + var2 + var3 + var4
>model <- try(glm(formula = fmla,   na.action=na.exclude , data = tmpData));
>summary(model) 
>    

                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   27.5192512  0.7215193  38.141  < 2e-16 ***
genderM                       -3.1572328  0.3952508  -7.988 1.87e-15 ***
age                            0.0078203  0.0139269   0.562   0.5745    
var1                          -0.0007449  0.0004484  -1.661   0.0968 .  
var2                           0.0284026  0.0017356  16.365  < 2e-16 ***
var3                           0.0007293  0.0005172   1.410   0.1586    
var4                           0.0854644  0.0418632   2.042   0.0413 *
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have defined gender as a factor (check the output of `class(gender)`). `glm()` treats each level of the factor other than the reference level (the first one in `levels(gender)`) as a dummy dichotomous variable (0 or 1) in the model, and outputs a regression coefficient for each.

If your factor had n levels, you would have n-1 dummy variables. If your factor has only two levels, as yours probably has, you only get one dummy variable and the coefficient is the same as if you had a numeric 0 or 1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is as if you had a dummy 0-1 variable, where 1 stands for `gender` being `M` (and presumably 0 stands for `F`).  So you are saying that allowing for the other variables, responses for cases with `gender` taking the value `M`  are about 3 below responses for cases with `F`.

Try this example

```
require(reshape)
mdata <- melt(UCBAdmissions) 
glm(mdata$value ~ mdata$Gender + mdata$Admit + mdata$Dept)
```

and you will get something similar.  The values for `mdata$DeptB`  and other departments are differences from the base position for `DeptA`.

Answer (score 0):

The contrast coefficients used for each variable in a linear model are determined by the contrasts attribute, which you can see and change by using the `contrasts()` function, e.g.:

```
require(reshape)
mdata <- melt(UCBAdmissions)
contrasts(mdata$Gender)
glm(mdata$value ~ mdata$Gender + mdata$Admit + mdata$Dept)
contrasts(mdata$Gender) <- c(-0.5, 0.5) # Use "deviation coding" instead
glm(mdata$value ~ mdata$Gender + mdata$Admit + mdata$Dept)
```

The default contrast coding for unordered factors is treatment contrasts/dummy coding. If you're unsure about the differences between these types of contrast coding, you may want to look at [stats.stackexchange.com](http://www.stats.stackexchange.com).